# Strange PG Error StatementInvalid

Tags: postgresql

We're getting on an off exceptions in PG. Googling doesn't turn any results.

The line in our code that triggers the exception is:

```
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
```

So we're thinking is somewhere in our stack. We're using ActiveRecord 3.2.12

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::Error: : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
    pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
    ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
    WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
    ORDER BY a.attnum
    :
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `async_exec'
    /bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `exec_no_cache'
```

Comment: is it possible your users table doesn't exist?

Comment: No it does exist. When we re-run this query manually it works. Also it happens sporadically

Comment: Is that the whole error message? That query is what AR uses to figure out the structure of the `users` table.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah exactly. At first we thought that the DB was corrupted, but running that query in the pg console does work. We're unsure what can it be.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect ActiveRecord. Look at this bit of your error-message:

```
PG::Error: : SELECT
```

That empty bit between ": :" is probably where your PostgreSQL error message should go.

Also - you say it's working some times and not others. That's not something you'd expect from the database. Make sure PostgreSQL is logging errors and then you can be sure.

You're probably looking at something like running out of connections, or network problems, or a resource problem in Ruby. Unfortunately, it looks like ActiveRecord is throwing the error messsage away.